# Converting an int array into a single string

Tags: java, arrays, string, jsp

It might look to be simple enough but I could not find an answer to it... I want to convert an array of doubles into single string in JSP (which is the same as in java I suppose)

So if I have an array:

```
double[] Array={1.6, 2.8, 3, 4.8, 5, 6, 7, 8.8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
```

How will I convert it into a single string:

```
String str;
```

for example!?

String str = Arrays.toString(Array) as many suggested did not work since jsp is a bit different to java I suppose...
Soved it now this way:

```
String str = ""; 
for(int i = 0; i<12; i++)
{
    nums += Double.toString(Array[i]) + ",";
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `str` to look like as a result?

Comment: lol. He change variable type))

Comment: @Andrei are you serious? :D

Comment: @Andrei class Arrays has methods toString(array) for all primitive types. Look at Jon Skeet's answer and also look at link that he posted for you.

Comment: Downvoted for being vague, inconsistent, and changing the question after several people have already answered it. Andrei, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Don't change your question again and again first make up mind. What you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) which:

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.

```
String res = Arrays.toString(intArray);
```

If `intArray` is [1, 9, 5]

`res` will be now: "[1, 9, 5]"

If you want the string to have the int elements concentrated you can do:

```
String res = "";
for(int num: intArray)
    res += num;
```

Now `res` will be 195

And of course you can put spaces between each number and so on..

After your edit, I see you have array of doubles. I think you can make the required changes.

Comment: i like this can edit the output as you wish example  res += num + ";"; Or use a string builder if big array

Comment: Indeed. StringBuilder is preferred for big arrays.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but Arrays.toString(Array) did not work in JSP... I tried that before posting, maybe I had to include some libriary or something... As far as I remember JSP slightly different to java anyway.

Comment: Found way around, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *didn't work*?

Comment: It was giving me an error: An error occurred at line: 21 in the jsp file: /index23.jsp Arrays cannot be resolved... Suppose JSP is a bit different to java...

Comment: its not. need to import, suggest you read basic tutorial on how to use jsps and j2ee in general. will help a lot

Comment: http://www.jsptut.com/directives.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Read this example: [*Java Convert int Array To String Example*](http://www.java-examples.com/java-convert-int-array-string-example)
You need toString method. do like this:

```
int[] intArray={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
String str=Arrays.toString(intArray);
```

Comment: You mean `Arrays.toString`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes Am I wrong?

Comment: This won't compile, you need `Arrays.` and not `intArray.`

Comment: @MarounMaroun sorry I made mistake

Comment: @MarounMaroun I am confuse I copied from OP question. and he is using double array...

Comment: `Arrays.toString()` can work on int[], double[], boolean[], char[]... That's OK. He changed it to double[].. god knows what he'll have after 5 minutes..

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes, actually OP change his question [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15716612/revisions)

Comment: The thing is Arrays.toString(intArray) did not work for me, int or double does not make a difference in fact...  I was getting an error - it is JSP, and some things do not work 100% the same as in java... maybe I had to incude something, but in java I have done this many times! It is solved now, thanks!

Comment: @AndreiIvanov You should state you question clearly, also you should sahre you answer in **Edit** part so that one can get help in future.  Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

Well you haven't said what you want the string to *look like*, but you might want [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) or [`Arrays.toString(double[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5B%5D%29) (as you've now changed the variable type). For example:

```
String text = Arrays.toString(array);
```

will give you `"[1.6, 2.8, 3, 4.8, 5, 6, 7, 8.8, 9, 10, 11, 12]"` for the sample data you gave.

If you want anything else, you should specify your requirements better.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but Arrays.toString(Array) did not work in JSP... I tried that before posting, maybe I had to include some libriary or something... As far as I remember JSP slightly different to java anyway.

Comment: @AndreiIvanov: Define "did not work"... and your context. Fundamentally your question is far too vague at the moment. Show *exactly* what you've tried, what happened, and whether you're actually interested in integers or doubles.

Comment: I solved it in a different way now...

Comment: But it was giving me an error: An error occurred at line: 21 in the jsp file: /index23.jsp
Arrays cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "";    

for(int i: intArray)
{
    str += i.toString() + " ";
}
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 5...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look into the [StringUtils.join()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28double%5b%5d,%20char%29) method of the [Apache Commons Lang project](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). Then it would be as simple as:

```
StringUtils.join(desiredSeparatorChar, doubleArray);
```

It'll give you more control of the resulting String than using `Arrays.toString()` suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
int[] intArray={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
String str = Arrays.toString(array);
System.out.print(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but Arrays.toString(Array) did not work in JSP... I tried that before posting, maybe I had to include some libriary or something... As far as I remember JSP slightly different to java anyway.

Comment: @AndreiIvanov : If your problem is solved, please mark it accepted.